# PostgreSQL | Need values from right table where is no match in m:n index

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a three tables issue with **PostgreSQL**

`table_left`, `table_index`, `table_right`

`table_index` is m:n ...

I want to get all values from right table matching (m:n) and not-matching (NULL) values based on the values of left table.

```
SELECT field_left, field_index1, field_index2,  field_right
  FROM table_left
    LEFT JOIN table_index ON left_id = index_left
        LEFT JOIN table_right ON index_right = right_id
```

Using this query I get all values from left to right, but I'm not getting values from table_right were are not based in m:n `table_index`

If I do something like this ...

```
SELECT field_left, field_index1, field_index2,  field_right
  FROM table_left
    LEFT JOIN table_index ON left_id = index_left
        LEFT JOIN table_right ON index_right = right_id OR right_id NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

... I will get some strange results ...

`field_index1`, `field_index2` using values from m:n but should be NULL because there is no dependency.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Have added some data ... Thx to @jarlh

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "table_index";
CREATE TABLE "public"."table_index" (
    "index_left" integer NOT NULL,
    "index_right" integer NOT NULL,
    "index_data1" character varying NOT NULL,
    "index_data2" character varying NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "table_index_index_left_index_right" PRIMARY KEY ("index_left", "index_right"),
    CONSTRAINT "table_index_index_left_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (index_left) REFERENCES table_left(left_id) NOT DEFERRABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "table_index_index_right_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (index_right) REFERENCES table_right(right_id) NOT DEFERRABLE
) WITH (oids = false);

INSERT INTO "table_index" ("index_left", "index_right", "index_data1", "index_data2") VALUES
(1, 1,  'index-Left-A', 'index-Right-A'),
(1, 2,  'index-Left-A', 'index-Right-B'),
(1, 3,  'index-Left-A', 'index-Right-C'),
(2, 1,  'index-Left-B', 'index-Right-A');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "table_left";
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS table_left_left_id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE table_left_left_id_seq INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 START 1 CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE "public"."table_left" (
    "left_id" integer DEFAULT nextval('table_left_left_id_seq') NOT NULL,
    "left_data" character varying NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "table_left_left_id" PRIMARY KEY ("left_id")
) WITH (oids = false);

INSERT INTO "table_left" ("left_id", "left_data") VALUES
(1, 'Left-A'),
(2, 'Left-B'),
(3, 'Left-C');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "table_right";
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS table_right_right_id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE table_right_right_id_seq INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 START 1 CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE "public"."table_right" (
    "right_id" integer DEFAULT nextval('table_right_right_id_seq') NOT NULL,
    "right_data" character varying NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "table_right_right_id" PRIMARY KEY ("right_id")
) WITH (oids = false);

INSERT INTO "table_right" ("right_id", "right_data") VALUES
(1, 'Right-A'),
(2, 'Right-B'),
(3, 'Right-C');
```

Using this query ....

```
SELECT left_id, left_data, index_left, index_right, index_data1, index_data2, right_id, right_data
  FROM table_left
    LEFT JOIN table_index ON left_id = index_left
        LEFT JOIN table_right ON index_right = right_id
```

... I get some NULL values as expected...

Using the original database I'm not getting these kind of values. Have seen there is an id col within the index table. Primary isn't set to both id values from left/right like my test. Have changed this in my local db with the same result as my test before. I'm getting these NULL values as expected.

Comment: Show us some sample table data, the current result and the wanted result - all as formatted text (no images). Simplify if possible, [mcve].

Comment: BTW, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: The database is read-only for me... I cannot post real data because of confidential. I need to create a local instance of pSQL to create some data.

Comment: Just make up some data. Values like 1, 2, 3 and A, B, C are perfect.

Comment: @jarlh - fyi .. I've added the dummy data to another answer because of character limit.

As you can see my dummy data works as expected. I'm checking with dev why the original part isn't working. Hope they can help me.

However .. How can I get values from right table within the same query which are not in table_index. I need the values from right table, of course.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all values from right table matching (m:n) and not-matching (NULL) values based on the values of left table.

If you want all values from the right table, then `left join` is the right way to go.  However the `right` table should be the first table in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT field_left, field_index1, field_index2,  field_right
FROM table_right r LEFT JOIN
     table_index i
     ON i.index_right = r.right_id LEFT JOIN
     table_left l
     ON l.left_id = i.index_left;
```

Notes:

- There is a bit of cognitive dissonance (in English) because the roles of left/right are reversed.
- I recommend that you use table aliases for your actual tables.
- I strongly, strongly recommend that you qualify *all* column references so it is clear what tables they come from.

You *could* also use `RIGHT JOIN`.  However, I also recommend using `LEFT JOIN` for this type of logic.  It is easier to follow query logic that says:  "Keep all rows in the table you just read" rather than "Keep all rows in some table that you will see much further down in the `FROM` clause."

EDIT:

Based on your comments, I suspect you want a Cartesian product of all left and right values along with a flag that indicates if it is in the junction table.  Something like this:

```
SELECT field_left, field_index1, field_index2,  field_right
FROM table_right r CROSS JOIN
     table_left l LEFT JOIN
     table_index i
     ON i.index_right = r.right_id AND
        i.index_left = l.left_id;
```

Comment: Created the query based on your input.

 `SELECT l.left_id, l.left_data, i.index_left, i.index_right, i.index_data1, i.index_data2, r.right_id, r.right_data
 FROM table_right r
   LEFT JOIN table_index i ON r.right_id = i.index_right
     LEFT JOIN table_left l ON i.index_left = l.left_id`

Result is that I get only information about all m:n dependencies...

Comment: Using this from left to right I will get all data from left and NULL from right, as expected. 

`SELECT l.left_id, l.left_data, i.index_left, i.index_right, i.index_data1, i.index_data2, r.right_id, r.right_data
FROM table_left l
  LEFT JOIN table_index i ON l.left_id = i.index_left
    LEFT JOIN table_right r ON i.index_right = r.right_id`

I missed only data which isn't used by m:n ... will make another try.